# Continuing a Thread After Sleeping

Tags: java, sleep, wakeup

I am currently writing a Java application that requires quite a lot of calls to the Twitter API. Because of this I have to worry about exceeding the rate limit. I figured out that I can make 180 calls per 14 minutes and then I have to wait a period of time before I can start calls to the API again (this number is returned in the application). So, when calls reach a certain number I have my thread sleep. My intention is to have the thread pick up where it left off automatically when sleep() is over. Does this work or do I have to worry about CPU scheduling and things like that!?

Maybe I don't fully understand how sleep is supposed to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated is seeing whether or not what I am doing is right. Thank you!

Below is just a couple of lines of pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
    if (calls are a certain number) 
    {
        Thread.sleep(840*1000);
        continue;
    }
      //CALL TO METHOD THAT REQUESTS INFORMATION FROM TWITTER API
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CyclicBarrier class.

Example from the CyclicBarrier's javadoc:

```
 class Solver {
   final int N;
   final float[][] data;
   final CyclicBarrier barrier;

   class Worker implements Runnable {
     int myRow;
     Worker(int row) { myRow = row; }
     public void run() {
       while (!done()) {
         processRow(myRow);

         try {
           barrier.await();
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           return;
         } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
           return;
         }
       }
     }
   }

   public Solver(float[][] matrix) {
     data = matrix;
     N = matrix.length;
     barrier = new CyclicBarrier(N,
                                 new Runnable() {
                                   public void run() {
                                     mergeRows(...);
                                   }
                                 });
     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
       new Thread(new Worker(i)).start();

     waitUntilDone();
   }
 }
```

You can use only two threads to solve this task, with simple Locks (from java.util.concurrent too). CyclicBarrier just provides more extensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, in [Java](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/java_barcode/) you can object.wait() with a timeout. Is this not what you want? If you want to change the timeout from another thread, change some 'waitValue' variable and notify(). The thread will then 'immediately' run and then wait again with the new timeout value. No explicit sleep required.